# How to deploy laravel application on aws using ftp

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

I want to host my laravel application on AWS, i have my application on bitbucket i want to clone my application on aws i have

```
Host : X.XXX.XXX.X
user : XXXXX
pwd  : key file
```

and phpmyadmin details as well.

How can i clone my project on aws.

Thanks

Comment: to clone you need access to your AWS terminal. Use any SSH client tool to log in to console and then you can use the git command to pull your code.

Comment: Read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Comment: you should be having an access for AWS, even if you upload it to AWS you won't be able to add domain under .conf to make it public.
you can clone that project on your local and upload it via ftp.
for compoer install you can create a file that run `exec` command with `composer install`  *Not recommended though*.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do via git, upload the project on git and pull it on server by login to server by ssh key, you can generate ssh key by puttygen and can login into server by putty.

Comment: Thanks but for that i should have terminal access but i have only ftp details